# how to populate nested composite type from JSON and insert into a table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-json

I am trying to convert a complex JSON into composite type. Here is an example

```
CREATE TYPE ty as(a int, b int[]);

CREATE TABLE ta(ab ty[]);

INSERT INTO ta(ab) values(ARRAY[ROW(1, ARRAY[1, 1])::ty, ROW(2, ARRAY[2, 2])::ty]);

select * from ta;
            ab                 
-----------------------------------
{"(1,\"{1,1}\")","(2,\"{2,2}\")"}
(1 row)
```

This works fine.

Now I am trying to insert a JSON array into the table by first populating it into the composite type and then insert it. The PostgreSQL function is throwing a weird error.

```
INSERT INTO ta(ab) values (json_populate_recordset(null::ty[], '[{"a":3,"b":[3,33]},{"a":4,"b":[4,44]}]'));
ERROR:  first argument of json_populate_recordset must be a row type

INSERT INTO ta(ab) values (json_populate_recordset(null::ty, '[{"a":3,"b":[3,33]},{"a":4,"b":[4,44]}]'));
ERROR:  column "ab" is of type ty[] but expression is of type ty
LINE 1: INSERT INTO ta(ab) values (json_populate_recordset(null::ty,...
                                   ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

This is just a sample that I am sharing, and actual JSON is generated from a couple of other functions. So I need to way to fix the JSON and then insert it into the table as a composite type. The one that works really close but not getting inserted is:-

```
INSERT INTO ta(ab) values (json_populate_recordset(null::ty, '[{"a":3,"b":"{3,33}"},{"a":4,"b":"{4,44}"}]'));
ERROR:  column "ab" is of type ty[] but expression is of type ty
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Notice how I have to convert the array into a JSON compatible array that PostgreSQL likes but this still doesn't work because there is a type cast issue.

So, I really want to solve two problems here:-

1. how to convert the JSON into a compatible JSON which json_populate_recordset likes, i.e. complex JSON getting serialized into a type(ty in our case).
2. How to resolve the type cast issue when trying to convert and insert the ARRAY of type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the type and aggregate from `jsonb_to_recordset`

```
insert into ta (ab)
select
    array_agg((
        a,
        (select array_agg(e::int) from jsonb_array_elements_text(b) jae(e))
    )::ty)
from jsonb_to_recordset(
    '[{"a":3,"b":[3,33]},{"a":4,"b":[4,44]}]'
) as v(a int, b jsonb)
```

Comment: Thanks Clodoaldo. It worked though it was very complicated to achieve it.